# почему изображение не двигается при нажатии клавиш?

Tags: python, python-3.x, классы, pygame, спрайт

часть кода в классе Gg, связанная с движением:

```
    def move(self):
        pressed_keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if pressed_keys[K_UP]:
            self.rect.move_ip(0, speed_gg_up)
        if pressed_keys[K_DOWN]:
            self.rect.move_ip(0, speed_gg_down)
```

это часть кода в игровом цикле

```
    for entity in gg_sprites:
        screen.blit(entity.image, entity.rect)
        entity.move
    gg_sprites.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.update()
```

у меня появляется изображение, но при нажатии клавиш "вверх" и/или "вниз" изображение не двигается. ошибки код не выдаёт. я не понимаю что я делаю не так

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему.

Comment: я постаралась убрать те моменты, которые не влияют на ошибку

Comment: Перейдите по ссылке которую вам предоставили и ознакомьтесь с правилами.